# Lower bound on symmetric square L-function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3990.pdf) of Soundararajan, equation (16c) states that for any Hecke eigenform $f$ of weight $k$, the symmetric square L-function at $1$ satisfies the bound
$$(\log k)^{-2}\ll L(1, \mathrm{sym}^2f)\ll(\log k)^2.$$
Where might I find a proof of this fact, and can one obtain similar bounds as the level of $f$ varies (a lower bound in particular)? The upper bound, perhaps with a slightly worse exponent, I think can be obtained from the approximate functional equation. The lower bound seems more subtle, however.

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.2307/2118544, where a proof is written up for Maass forms, and the exact same proof goes through for holomorphic forms (and the authors mention this).

Comment: As you note the upper bound is a bit inaccurate, and the exponent should be $3$.  The lower bound follows from the fact that these $L$-functions have no Siegel zeros, as Peter Humphries points out above.   You may also wish to look at Xiannan Li's paper on upper bounds for $L$-values (in IMRN).  Upper bounds in general are ok, and a classical zero free region will give lower bounds of that shape.